# How to clear all filters in xlsx using phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

How to remove all filters in a worksheep using phpspreadsheet?
Don't find any solution in documentation.

Want to make programmatically analog of this:

> Remove all the filters in a worksheet
> If you want to completely remove filters, go to the Data tab and click the Filter button, or use the keyboard shortcut Alt+D+F+F.

Sory for my english.

Comment: do you try deleteRule ? https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/classes/PhpOffice-PhpSpreadsheet-Worksheet-AutoFilter-Column.html#method_deleteRule

Comment: do you have any code-example?) don't work correctly...

Comment: @DonKnacki inside columns loop, i try this code: $dataSheet->getAutoFilter()->getColumn(Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($columnIndex))->clearRules(); When i open my xlsx, all records are hidden. But in every filter selected "all". It's strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was suggested by the developers on the project: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/discussions/3367#discussioncomment-4984548